# Constants as input to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, constants, user-input

Say in my js file I want to have

```
var NO = 0;
var YES = 1;

function doYouLikeCake(answer){}
```

When doYouLikeCake is called from another file, I want to be able to input YES or NO, but I'm not sure how to do that if those variables are defined in the js file. Is this possible?

EDIT: Nevermind the HTML bit. No, there are no buttons. I'm trying to make a library, and want to simplify it so that the users of the library can just write doYouLikeCake(YES) rather than having to define YES/NO themselves.

Comment: "called from a html file" - do you mean attribute handlers such as `onclick="..."`?

Comment: i'm guessing you have some buttons in your html file? if so then you should use true for yes and false for no: example:     <button onclick="doYouLikeCake(true);">yes</button>
    <button onclick="doYouLikeCake(false);">no</button>

Comment: Call it like `onclick="doYouLikeCake(NO)"`. That will pass 0 to the answer argument of the function.

Comment: then in the function it self you could do if(answer){//its true some code}else{//its false do this code}

Comment: So what's your question? Your users can write doYouLikeCake(YES)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="doYouLikeCake(YES);" value="Yes">
<input type="submit" onclick="doYouLikeCake(NO);" value="No">

<script>

    var NO = 0;
    var YES = 1;

    function doYouLikeCake(answer) { 
        //... 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The use of global variables should be minimized.

Comment: The asker wants constants. Globals are the most appropriate for emulating this behavior. Not commenting on whether he should be doing this in the first place though.

Comment: Certainly not. Constants are of course namespace-agnostic. They don't care if they're globals or bound to a local namespace. As I said, the use of global variables should be minimized. Therefore, it is recommended to assign the constants to your own namespace: `APP.YES = true;`, and then `onclick="APP.doYouLikeCake( APP.YES )"`.

Answer (score 0):

The boilerplate would be...

```
(function () {

    var YES = true;
    var NO = false;

    // All your JavaScript code here

}());
```

So, you want to put your "constants" inside your namespace, which can be achieved by an IIFE (like in my example above), or a DOM-ready handler. All your code should reside inside that namespace, which ensures that your "constants" are available to your code.

---

Btw, you can create real constants by creating non-writable properties:

```
Object.defineProperty( APP, 'YES', {
    value: true,
    enumerable: true
});
```

where `APP` is the namespace for the constant.

Answer (score 0):

here's the example from my comment above: http://jsfiddle.net/vhQ8T/

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are defined in the js file, you'll need to update the html element dynamically from the script.

For example this could be your html:

```
<input type="radio" name="YesOrNo" id="NO" value="PlaceHolderForNo" />NO
<input type="radio" name="YesOrNo" id="YES" value="PlaceHolderForYes" />YES
```

And your js:

```
var NO=0;
var YES=1;

var inputNO=document.getElementById("NO");
var inputYES=document.getElementById("YES");
```

// these are your variables

```
inputNO.value=NO; 
inputYES.value=YES;

inputNO.onclick=function(){doYouLikeCake(this.value);};
inputYES.onclick=function(){doYouLikeCake(this.value);};
```

The live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WhHXK/

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to input them. Just reference them since they are being declared in the global scope.

```
function doYouLikeCake()
{
    return YES;
}
```